# Cannot export android application by enabling proguard+using parse sdk 1.8.2

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification, proguard

```
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Proguard returned with error code  1. See console[2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips]  Warning:com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Request$Callback
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$Builder
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionDefaultAudience
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.TokenCachingStrategy
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.FacebookError
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.FacebookError
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request$Callback
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.FacebookRequestError
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.model.GraphObject
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request$Callback
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.FacebookRequestError
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.model.GraphObject
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Request
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Response
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] Warning: there were 86 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
   [2015-03-27 19:03:33 - BeautyTips]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

**My project's database is hosted in parse.com and i have been using push notification using parse.com.The parse sdk used here is sdk 1.8.2.This is the error i am getting in console..how to solve this..pls help me?**

Comment: **My problem got solved..just add the following in proguard-project.txt **  _-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}_

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to your proguard file:

```
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
```